# Visual Studio's "Track Active Item In Solution Explorer" doesn't quite do enough

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

We have a huge solution file. If the active file appears in an EXPANDED node of the the Solution Explorer, the file is highlighted, but if the containing parent nodes are not expanded, the file is not highlighted.

Is there some utility that would locate the file in the Windows Explorer on demand or automatically expand the parent nodes to reveal the file in the explorer?

Comment: This works fine in VS2010 on Win7.  Don't make us guess at your version of VS and Windows.

Comment: I find it interesting that the version of Windows is a factor. Perhaps everyone should note the OS, level and patches with every post so one doesn't have to guess. I'm on Win XP SP2. I am unable to verify, but I could have sworn that I have the same issue on Windows 7 with VS2010. I'll verify later and post my finding.

Comment: The "Track Active Item" feature has always been a little buggy and the bigger the projects and solutions the buggier it has been.  However, I don't recall observing the particular symptoms you are reporting, nor can I reproduce them now.

Comment: It works when I use 2010 on my home PC but not 2008

Comment: I have the same problem with VS2010 SP1 on Win7 x64

Comment: I have the same problem with VS2010 SP1 on WinXP SP3

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on a quite big solution file. Used to work fine on the same solution and works fine in other solutions.

I'd say the OS probably doesn't matter, but maybe TFS does. 
Visual 2010
TFS

Answer (score 0):

For those using Resharper - you can **right click** on **solution root** → **Expand All** → **Collapse All**.

Then it works for me in VS2010.